# SP13 - Create Standart view(Tasks in the week & tasks complete last week)

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-view

I want to create Startdart view for TASK LIST(*list template*). I want to **filter** tasks only for this week. How to do this ?

[image]

Thank you previously!

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below link which filter the list view for current week

https://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2008/05/14/filter-list-view-by-current-week/